# Automaticly shut down Ubuntu

Tags: shutdown, automatic

Is it possible to set some sort of script that automaticly turns off the computer at certan time, for example at 10pm.
I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It is unclear if you want to do it once or daily.

Comment: @Pilot6 scripts tend to be re-usable :)

Comment: Well, your solution does it once, mine daily. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
0 22 * * * root poweroff
```

to `/etc/crontab`

That will turn off computer daily at 10pm.

Comment: Can you explain me the process step by step?

Comment: Open the file e.g. by nano `sudo nano /etc/crontab` and add the line there below everything else. Ctrl+X to exit.

Comment: I should add 0 22 * * * root poweroff to /etc/crontab in script made from notepad, shold't I? In which format should I save the script? Or i can just run it in the terminal?

Comment: You don't add a script. You run in a terminal `sudo nano /etc/crontab`, the file will open, and you add the line to the text file.

Comment: this turns off the pc daily, right? I have tried 3 hours ago and it worked perfectly.

Comment: That is correct. It is daily.

Comment: Update: some of the computers don't turn off with the above line entered in the crontab. I tried with poweroff and shutdown but nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ask another question with details on what are the computers, what are you doing and what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The shutdown command allows for a delayed action.

```
shutdown -h 22:00
```

shuts the system down at 22:00 IF the system is running.

```
shutdown -r +1440
```

will shutdown in 24 hours (1440/60=24) so tomorrow at the current time.

If you want more elaborate methodes install [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at). That allows things like "at sunday", or "next week", "now + 120 min" and so on.

These commands need to be repeated every time you want this. Follow pilot6's answer to add a command to cron. If you use commands make sure to use absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

For example you could use a crontab: enter `sudo crontab -e` (this opens the crontab file for the root user)
At the end on a new line you enter the following(it will shutdown the computer at 22PM):

```
0 22 * * * shutdown -P now >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will shutdown 
The Syntax is:

```
* * * * * COMMAND
```

Beforte the command there are 5 thins to give: 
1. Minute, 2. Hour, 3. Day of Month, 4. Month, 5. Day of Week.
All have to be true. If you put a star it accepts every value there. So you could also say execute a command at 7 AM, if it is a Friday the 13th:  `0 7 13 * 5 /alert.sh`